# Performance Profiling for Firefox on Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2016, terminal-server, firefox

I have a problem with high CPU load, caused by Firefox (60.6.2 ESR) sessions on a Windows Server 2016 Terminal Server I'm maintaining.

However, in Windows Task manager, I can only see the firefox instances, but not what in firefox causes the high CPU load. I do know about the firefox-internal task manager (about:performance) but I do not see how to analyze firefox instances of other users.

Is it possible to profile the performance of other firefox instances, so I can check which pages / webapps or whatever are causing the high load? My guess is that some user visits inappropriate sites like youtube or music streaming sites (for which the terminal server isn't designed).